# ACF custom post feed by custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using wordpress with custom post type UI plugin and ACF plugin. 
Trying to build a “single” template with multiple feeds of custom post types by custom custom taxonomy. Using this code, with a few variations to figure out what am i doing wrong.

Got 2 pieces of code like this in a row

```
<?php if( get_field('collectiona') ): 
    $argsc = array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'product-collections' => get_field('collectiona'),
    );
    $prods2 = new WP_Query( $argsc );
    if( $prods2->have_posts() ) {
      while( $prods2->have_posts() ) {
        $prods2->the_post();
        ?> 
       Whatever post code
      <?php
      }
    }
    else {
      echo '';
    }
  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

`collectiona` is a taxonomy field. With the piece of code, shown above, it just shows all the “products” posts out there. I’ve also tried using a text field with taxonomy slug. It shows first feed perfectly fine, if i’m not using first if statement (`<?php if( get_field(‘collectiona’) ): ?>`), and if that statement is present- same thing happens. All the “products” are shown. However, even with first feed shown fine, 2nd feed still shows all the “products” out there. Despite what taxonomy slug says.

I’m trying to build it the way, admin could chose a dropdown taxonomy. Text field with taxonomy slug is just an example.
p.s.
I use term object
Full template code is here jsfiddle.net/pudfbxhv . I know jsfiddle is useless for wp templates, but that's a pretty big piece of code

**EDIT**

Here is updated code

```
<?php
            $taxterms = get_field("collectiona"); ?>                

                <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'products',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product-collections',
                            'field' => 'id',
                            'terms' => $taxterm->term_id
                        )
                    )
                );

                $myquery = new WP_Query( $args );
                if($myquery->have_posts()) : ?>

                    <ul>
                        <?php while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>
                            <li> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_field('prod_featured_image'); ?>" onmouseover="this.src='<?php the_field('prod_hover_featured_image'); ?>'" onmouseout="this.src='<?php the_field('prod_featured_image'); ?>'" /></a>
                                                             <h2><?php the_field('prod_subtitle'); ?></h2>
                                                             <p>$<?php the_field('prod_price'); ?></p>
                                                            </li>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `var_dump( get_field( 'collectiona' ) );`

Comment: bool(false) , but value is selected in post editor

Comment: Then you are not using this function on a single page, you are using it out of context, that is why you are getting no value. Or you are using `query_posts` somewhere on your single template which **will** pass wrong info

Comment: There is no query_posts in the template. And not sure i'm following about single page. It's used in one template for a single custom post. btw, here is full php template of it https://jsfiddle.net/pudfbxhv/

Comment: Please add your code in your question. Your fiddle is useless as it does not work on Wordpress. I am talking about your single post page, `single.php` or `single-{$post_type}.php`

Comment: I know it's useless, but it's a pretty big piece of code to insert in here, and jsfiddle has pretty good highlighting, so, it's easier to read. But let me know if you want the whole thing here.

Comment: You will get nothing, you need to set post ids to your fields as they are used outside of loops. That is most probably your issue

Comment: so, apparently there was supposed to be tax_query. Copied that piece of code (updated question) from acf support forum. And still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0):

Well, that may be a perversion, but it worked for me.

```
$termss = get_field('collectiona');
    $slll = $termss->slug;
    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'products',
      'product-collections' => $slll,
    );
    $lineblocks = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( $lineblocks->have_posts() ) {
      while( $lineblocks->have_posts() ) {
        $lineblocks->the_post();
```

Also, gotta remember to put the following code after every array

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```